# JQuery On Click Event not firing with JS created elements

Tags: javascript, jquery, onclick

I am still learning JS and JQuery and am running into an issue with the on click event not firing. I have created a menu with titles that should be clickable.

```
            var title = document.createElement('h1');
            title.textContent = "HW Tools";
            title.className += "SelectableMenu";
            hwSection.appendChild(title);
```

In the Jquery portion, I have:

```
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $("#Menu_HW_Main").on('click', '.SelectableMenu', function () {
            alert("Test");
        })
```

where #Menu_HW_Main is the id for the div containing the menu.
However, when I click on the title, the alert does not show.

When I create the title/menu in the DOM, the event fires fine. But when I create it through JS, it does not fire. What am I missing?

Comment: can you provide a fiddle?

Comment: is #Menu_HW_Main also generated with js ?

Comment: make sure you delegate the click on  a selector thats there from the beginn, like $(document).on( ...

Comment: What you need to do exactly ? If you want to work with current elements in menu after click, you can do better solution than you have now.

Comment: There's no issue with your code, assuming certain missing parts are actually present. We don't need a "fiddle". We need a complete and fully verified demonstration of the issue.

Comment: "When I create the title/menu in the DOM, the event fires fine. But when I create it through JS, it does not fire...". What does that even mean? DOM APIs are JavaScript.

Comment: @undefined I think they mean in the HTML source.

Comment: You already have a reference to the element, why not just do `$(title).on('click' ...)`

Comment: @johnSmith is correct. You are also dynamically generating the delegated element so it seems. You should just attach it to document if the original div container isnt there. As long as $("#Menu_HW_Main") is there on the intial page load the code looks fine to me

Comment: Thanks everyone. The #Menu_HW_Main was created in JS and was not part of the document originally. I used $(document).on(... and it is working fine now. How would you use the selector on dynamically created elements?

Comment: In order to fully help, you need to show us a complete concise example that includes enough code to reproduce the issue.  In this case, you failed to show the relevant HTML.   Please read:  http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Answer (score 0):

Your code seems fine but instead of mixing vanilla `JS` you may use only `jQuery` to create the `h1`:

```
var h1 = $('<h1/>', {'text':'HW Tools', 'class':'SelectableMenu'});

$("#Menu_HW_Main").append(h1);
```

If `"#Menu_HW_Main"` is also a dynamic (created by `js`) element then try this:

```
$(document).on('click', '.SelectableMenu', function () {
    alert("Test");
});
```